# Простейший зацикленный таймер обратного отсчета

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток, как сделать обычный таймер например от 10 секунд и до 0, и после окончания начинал снова отсчитывать от 10 до 0. Буду очень признателен если напишите код, unity только начал изучать. Пытался искать в интернете Unity постоянно выдает ошибки. Делаю в Unity 5.

Comment: А причем тут юнити? Код пишется на языке `C#` или `javascript`. напишите в начале на нем, а потом делайте с ним все, что захотите в юнити

Comment: Код на C# находил, который работал на старой версии юнити, сейчас в 5 версии юнити пришли нововведения. Вот и прошу знающих, помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float time = .0f;

IEnumerator Timer () {
time = 10.0f
while (time > 0.0f) {
        time -= Time.deltaTime;
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate ();
    }
Debug.Log ("done");
StartCoroutine (Timer());

    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?